# Substituting JS variable into a string that is a jinja template

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io, jinja2, flask-socketio

My client side event handler is as follows:

```
socket.on('received_message',function(data){
           console.log(data);

           var actual="{% if "+int(data['user_id'])+"==current_user.id %}<div class=\"user\" id=\"postof"+data['post_id']+"\"\"><span><strong><u>"+data['username']+"</u></strong></span><a href=\"{{url_for('delete_post',post_id="+data['post_id']+",thread_id="+data['thread_id']+")}}\">Delete</a><p>"+data['msg']+"</p></div>{% else %}<div class=\"notuser\" id=\"postof"+data['post_id']+"\"><span><strong><u>"+data['username']+"</u></strong></span><p>"+data['msg']+"</p></div>{% endif %}";
           console.log("{{dif_user}}")
           console.log('{{current_user.id}}'+"  "+data['user_id']);
           console.log(actual);
           document.getElementById('posts').innerHTML+=actual;
           $('.container').scrollTop($('.container')[0].scrollHeight);
         });
```

My server side call for the above event handler is

```
socketio.emit('received_message',{'room':data['room'],'user_id':p.user_id,'username':user_.username,'msg':p.message,'post_id':p.id,'thread_id':thread_.id},room=data['room'],dif_user=p.user_id)
```

Right now the code doesnt work properly as the jinja code inserted always results in execution of else part. How do i incorporate the  js variable `data['user_id']` into the `actual` variable i created so that flask renders it properly.

I think flask is taking the substituted `data['user_id']` as a string due to which the else part is getting executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to consider that the Jinja template executes when the template is returned via render_template, so the decision to use the if block or the else block will be made at that time with the values of variables at that time. The conditional will not be re-evaluated when the Socket.IO event is received by the client, because the event will be received in the client without Python's intervention.

If you want the client to evaluate a conditional at the time the Socket.IO event is received, then you have to write the conditional in JavaScript.

Comment: If Jinja templates are rendered during load time with the help of render_template , and cannot be rendered during socketio events , then how is that in my code the code being added is always the else part of the Jinja , doesn't this mean Jinja is actually being evaluated even during socketio events

Comment: No, that means that the page in the client only has the "else" part of your Jinja conditional, because that is the part that executed when render_template was invoked. Look at the HTML page source in your browser to confirm.